# Expressing a regular level set as a regular zero set for any smooth real-valued function

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm a little confused about Lemma 9.7 of Tu's An Introduction to Manifolds. Below is the statement of the lemma and the proof.

[image]

I don't really understand how Tu is saying that $f_{\ast,p}$ equals $g_{\ast,p}$ for all $p \in N$. These maps have different codomains $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ and $T_{g(p)}\mathbb{R}$ (as vector spaces they are isomorphic however) respectively but the derivations depend on the bases of these spaces. If anyone could explain what Tu means by $f_{\ast,p}$ equals $g_{\ast,p}$ that would be great.

Comment: You don't really need to worry about the tangent space to $\mathbb{R}$, since there is no issue in identifying the different tangent spaces (like there is, say, on a curved manifold). The point is that $f$ and $g$ differ by a constant, so their derivatives are equal.

Comment: Right so I understand the idea is that since $f$ and $g$ differ by a constsnt their derivatives are equal. But the differential is defined a little differently (as pre composition in tu at least). Can you give a little more detail showing why their differentials are actually equal as maps? Or why a point is regular in $f$ if and only if its regular in $g$?

Comment: You may recall that in your analysis course you did not differentiate between any tangent spaces on $\Bbb R^n$. This is because these may all be canonically identified. $\Bbb R^n$ is a Lie group (its even abelian), so you may use translations to identify any two tangent spaces.

Comment: Right, so I can do that but there still an issue I can't resolve. We can identify $C_{g(p)}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $C_{f(p)}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ by the map $h \mapsto h-c$. So $f_{\ast}(X_{p})$ and $g_{\ast}(X_{p})$ have the same domain and codomain ($X_{p} \in T_{p}N$). But under this isomorphism $X_{p}(h \circ g)$ and $X_{p}((h-c) \circ f)$ don't agree because $h \circ g$ and $(h-c) \circ f$ don't agree as germs ($h \in C_{g(p)}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}$)).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with $h-c\circ f$ and $h\circ g$, I think you have confused yourself (at any rate, there many functions that have different germs in the stalk $C^\infty_p$ but still have the same derivative). The situation is simple, let $x\in M$ and $X$ be a derivation in $T_xM$. Then $df(X)=X(f)=X(g-c)=X(g)-X(c)=X(g)=dg(X)$. We see that the two derivatives $df$ and $dg$ agree, so $f$ and $g$ have the same critical points.